# Access parent variable VueJS 2

Tags: parent-child, vuejs2

I have a .Vue with some child template:

```
<template>
  <test></test>
</template>
...
export default {
  data() {
    hello: '';
  }
}
```

In test.vue I'm trying to access 'hello', but I can't. I've tried using 'props', but no luck. How do I achieve this simple task?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually straightforward with props. Maybe it didn't work because of the syntax error in your `data` function?

**parent.vue:**

```
<template>
    <test :my-prop="hello"></test>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            hello: 'foobar'
        }),
        // ...
    };
</script>
```

**test.vue:**

```
<template>...</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['myProp'],
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.myProp); // foobar
        }
    };
</script>
```